# How can I design VHDL modal in the following details?

Tags: unit-testing, vhdl, xilinx

Design VHDL model of a functional unit called sign-extender unit used in some processors. Input of this unit is 4-bit signed binary number and output is 8 bit signed binary number. The unit preserves magnitude and sign of the number.

Here is my code and it doesn't work. I'm beginner. Please help and explain. Many thanks.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity sign_extender is
    port
    (   
        a: in std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
        q: out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
    );
end sign_extender;

architecture sign_extender_arch of sign_extender is
begin -- architecture
    q <= a;
end sign_extender_arch;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
q <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(a), q'length));
```

The `std_logic_vector` doesn't represent an integer value, only an array of `std_logic`, so first you make it `signed` using `signed` from  `ieee.numeric_std.signed`.

A `resize` function is also defined in `ieee.numeric_std` for `signed` and `unsigned`, and it is applied to the `signed` value, with the desired length given by `q'length`, and it returns a `signed` for `signed` argument, etc.

Finally the `signed` value is converted back to `std_logic_vector`, as required for the output port.

Comment: Re: "...`std_logic_vector` doesn't represent a value, only an array of `std_logic`, so first...". See IEEE Std 1076-2008, 5.3.2 Array types, 5.3.2.1 General, para 1, "The value of an array object is a composite value consisting of the values of its elements.". Your answer is correct, the reason is not. See 9.3.6 Type conversions, para 1, "A type conversion provides for explicit conversion between closely related types." and 5.1 para 2 "A type is characterized by a set of values and a set of operations. ...". There is no subprogram that provides sign extension for std_logic_vector.

Comment: @DavidKoontz: I have updated the description to say "doesn't represent an **integer** value".  Appears that new VHDL users often hits that hurdle.

Answer (score 2):

"Morten Zilmer" presented a good idea. Another way is to extend it manually without any additional function such as the following code :

```
q <= ( 7 downto 4 => a(3) ) & a;
```